# Div dropdown menu show/hide onclick jquery

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to implement a div dropdown menu.

JQuery here:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.desplegar').click(function() {
            $(this).next("div.desplegar_fills").show().siblings("div.desplegar_fills").hide();              
        });
    });
</script>
```

I know this jquery would only work to show Subindex level, but I can't even make it work.

HTML here:

```
<div class="desplegar">
        <p>Index 1</p>
        <div class="desplegar_fills">
            <p>Subindex 1</p>
            <div class="desplegar_links">
                <a href="#">Enllaç 1</a>
                <a href="#">Enllaç 2</a>
                <a href="#">Enllaç 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="desplegar">
        <p>Index 2</p>
        <div class="desplegar_fills">
            <p>Subindex 2</p>       
            <div class="desplegar_links">
                <a href="#">Enllaç 1</a>
                <a href="#">Enllaç 2</a>
                <a href="#">Enllaç 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="desplegar">
        <p>Index 3</p>
        <div class="desplegar_fills">
            <p>Subindex 3</p>       
            <div class="desplegar_links">
                <a href="#">Enllaç 1</a>
                <a href="#">Enllaç 2</a>
                <a href="#">Enllaç 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

It should look like this:

[image: It should look like this]

So, if I click on Index 1 it shows Subindex 1 and if i click on Subindex 1 it shows the links. The thing is, if I click on Index 2 or Index 3, Index 1 should close and just display Subindex 2 or Subindex 3(depending on which clicked). Any sugestions? Thanks to everyone!

Comment: You don't appear to have asked a question. Do you have a problem with your code?

Comment: Yeah, i've tried to implement the dropdown menu and im not able. I've tried many things and I can't get it right..

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried.

Comment: Okay, I will right now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Find the answer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/650t6p9w/).

Basically this script should do the job:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.desplegar_fills').hide(0);
    $('.desplegar_links').hide(0);
    $('.desplegar').click(function() {
        $('.desplegar_fills').hide(0);
        $('.desplegar_links').hide(0);
        $(this).find(".desplegar_fills").show(0);
    });
    $('.desplegar_fills').click(function(e){
        $('.desplegar_links').hide(0);
        $(this).find(".desplegar_links").show(0);
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
});
```